# how to pull three tabular columns in a main page in apex?

Tags: apex

I have a application with which I have 4 pages . one is main page with select list and other 3 are pages with tabular form each .Now I want to have  tabular forms of those three pages in my main page from where I could call tabular forms of all these pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use your remaining 3 pages on your main page via HTML iframe like in html region

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="f?p=&APP_ID.:PAGE_ID:&APP_SESSION.::NO::"
seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height: 100px;
float: left;">   </iframe>
```